# How open file in 2 different type editors in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea

There is a `business.bpmn` file and `actiBMP` plugin which opens this file and show a image. The problem comes in when it is needed to edit this file as xml. Is there a way to open it as xml in Intellij idea without deleting the plugin?

**Note 1**

The `actiBMP` has `view as xml` button, but it just view, without editing possibility.

**Note 2**

There some similar question about opening 1 file in 2 editors via `Split Vertically`/`Split Horizaontally`, but question is not about that. The question is about how open same file as `bmpn` and `xml` at the same time.